# PowerShell does not recognize Visual Studio Code commands

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code

Calling `code .` in PowerShell leads to an `The term is not recognized`-error.

Running Windows 10 with latest updates. I've tested this with PowerShell on both Microsoft Terminal and Wezterm. Works fine with CMD as shell.

Currently, I can't run `code .` in PowerShell as it fails with the error:

```
PS C:\Users\<USER>> code .
C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft : The term 'C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft' is not
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\<USER>\...grams\Microsoft:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

This issue persists, even after restarts and reinstalling VSCode. It used to complain about not finding `C:\Program` when `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin` was in the path.

This is my path:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.13.8-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.312.7-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-8.0.312.7-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-11.0.13.8-hotspot\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe;C:\HaxeToolkit\neko;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\WezTerm;%HAXEPATH%;%NEKO_INSTPATH%;C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
```

`Get-Command code -All` return the following:

```
PS C:\Users\<USER>> Get-Command code -All

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     code.cmd                                           0.0.0.0    C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd
Application     code                                               0.0.0.0    C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code
```

Things I've attempted:

- Restart
- Reinstall VSCode
- `powershell -NoProfile`
- `$env:Path = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;$env:Path"`

It's very clearly failing because empty spaces are present in the path, but I don't know why it started to complain now while it worked perfectly before and how to fix it. Might be related to this issue as well ([Running libraries with Haxelib leads to `Module not found`, printing out a path containing ^'s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77138156/running-libraries-with-haxelib-leads-to-module-not-found-printing-out-a-path)), as they both came up recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system environment variable `ComSpec` was falsely set to `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`. Changing it back to `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` fixed this issue.

No idea why it changed in the first place, but I would've never found this error if not for the help of [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi) who found the answer in the context of [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77138156/45375), whose symptom was caused by the same problem.

Thanks a ton!